# How to connect Arch Linux Guest to Virtual Box Bridged Network (Wireless NIC)

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, virtualbox, arch-linux, bridge

I've tried to install Arch Linux as a VirtualBox VM a couple of days ago. Everything worked like a charm - if there hadn't been that issue that I can't connect to anything when I set the VM to use a bridged adapter.

**What I want to achieve**

- Guest can connect to local network
- Guest can connect to the internet
- Others on local network can connect to guest.

**My Setup**

*Host*

- Windows 10 Pro
- VirtualBox 5.0.20
- Intel WiFi NIC (connected to local network)
- Latest updates installed
- Virtual NIC set to bridged adapter and Paravirtualized (Virtio-net)

*Guest*

- Arch Linux (up to date)
- *virtualbox-guest-utils* installed
- *net-tools* installed
- x64 Machine
- VBox-Addins do work (shared folders, etc... working!)
- **no GUI, just terminal**

What am I missing out on? This can't be so hard, can it? Does it even work with WiFi? Or do I need to connect the host to the network via ethernet?

Please help me, I'm really, really lost here...

Answer (score 0):

On 5.0.20, my Ubuntu guest is able to connect in bridged mode only when using an Ethernet connection -- i.e. not when using a wireless connection.

NAT mode is able to work with a wireless connection.

Answer (score 0):

To let Archlinux virtual machine use a VirtualBox's bridged network adaptor, just install and enable the correct kernel modules and DHCP service! Even wireless adaptors work!

```
sudo pacman -S dhcpcd virtualbox-guest-utils-nox
sudo systemctl enable --now vboxservice
sudo systemctl enable --now dhcpcd
```

Cheers!